# EMV Rupay application selection not working

Tags: smartcard, smartcard-reader, emv

I have successfully read Card Details using Chip for Master & Visa cards, but for Rupay card while selecting AID (A0000005241010) card reader returns response as 6A82, also it is observed that the Rupay card is using T1 communication. Is their any additional steps for Rupay Card apart from PSE/looping AIDS?

Comment: Why do you think it is RuPay card? What  card replied to PSE/PPSE commands? Add APDU traces.

Comment: i am using chip reader hence there is no need to check ppse right, below are the steps


1.PSE Check 
request : 00A404000E315041592E5359532E444446303100
response : 6A82
2.Since not pse loop aids, since i know it is rupay card from logo on card, skipping forward with rupay aid
request : 00A4040007A0000005241010
response : 6A82
ps : the protocol used is t1 (as per atr and desktop client), for other rupay card with t0 protocol above method works fine.
Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: Do you have the rupay specification ?

Comment: i dont, but on there official site they have mentioned that rupay is emv compatible

Comment: Send Select Command "00 A4 04 00 07 A000000524 1010 00", i.e. with Byte Le = "00" after AID.

Comment: did that same output, i have used A0000005241010 command with another rupay card with T0 protocol and it seems to work fine, its is only with T1 protocol i am facing problem

Comment: T=1 protocol is communication data transmission layer. Usually smartcard readers allow to sent APDU commands and get replies using specific API without going deeper into card protocol layer. In case you'd like to work at communication protocol layer directly you need to implement T=1 Block Frames for APDU Command requests and to extract card replies from similar frames. T=0 and T=1 protocols defined in ISO 7816 Part 3 "Electronic signals and transmission protocols".

Answer (score 0):

As far i have knowledge, there is no card certified for Rupay with T=1 protocol. It may be a case that Rupay is not loaded on this card.
Here is a list of certified product [Rupay DI Card Applet Product List](https://www.npci.org.in/sites/default/files/circular/RuPay%20DI%20Card%20Applet%20Product%20List%201.4.pdf)